# При вставки видео с ютуб через <iframe> выходят ошибки в консоли

Tags: html, css, iframe

Вставил на сайте видео с ютуба через iframe, но есть такая проблема, что страница подгружается бесконечно и в консоли периодически выходят следующие ошибки:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED   
    
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
       
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
        
POST https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true&authuser=0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`
```

А при запуске видео выходят следующие ошибки, но при этом видео показывается:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?backend=innertube&cname=56&cver=20221127&foc_id=edskVwIKiZJsO8XdJdLKnA&label=followon_view&ptype=no_rmkt&random=278331271&cv_attributed=0' (redirected from 'https://www.youtube.com/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?backend=innertube&cname=56&cver=20221127&foc_id=edskVwIKiZJsO8XdJdLKnA&label=followon_view&ptype=no_rmkt&random=278331271') from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
 GET https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?backend=innertube&cname=56&cver=20221127&foc_id=edskVwIKiZJsO8XdJdLKnA&label=followon_view&ptype=no_rmkt&random=278331271&cv_attributed=0 net::ERR_FAILED 302
```

Ключевым является наверное следующее сообщение:

```
from origin 'https://www.youtube.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Но я не понимаю в чём дело и как это исправить, помогите пожалуйста
Вот на всякий

scss:

```
experts__video {
        flex: 0 1 50%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0px 0px 27.5% 0px;
        iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
    }
```

html:

```
<div  class="experts__video">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sohdv21BVNI" title="YouTube video player"
    frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; 
    gyroscope; picture-in-picture"allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас скорее всего стоит Adblock Plus. Если да, то  отключите его, ошибки пропадут.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/824884)